# Android Collada

Tags: android, collada

Does anyone know a tutorial or an example on how to load .dae (COLLADA) files in Android and use this files with OpenGL-Es ?

Answer (score 0):

Build it :) there are some importers out there but none which are very robust. http://www.anddev.org/opengl-es_load_collada_file-t5077.html